If I work for a municipality, then why do I have to pay property taxes?
Why do I have to pay property taxes if I work for a municipality?
So I pay x amount of dollars for my owned property and then the same people I pay taxes to, pays me.

Closely related, maybe a duplicate: Why do government employees pay income taxes?.

Please ask the school tax question separately. The “why pay property tax” question is essentially a duplicate of an already-asked question, and is basically unrelated to “why pay school tax.”

I've cut the school question out and voted to close as a duplicate.  For the school question, you went to school so you benefitted from education, you're paying that back as an adult.  You also benefit from other people's children going to school, because you and they are part of the same economy.  Other people are your customers, if they are poor, you are poor too.

I do think we've seen the school tax if not kids question before as well.  Though it might have gotten deleted.

@ItalianPhilosopher - Why do property taxes fund schools when only a subset of residents actually use said schools?
